# I am using Netbeans IDE, how to resolve "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"?

Tags: java, netbeans

Code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
    package com.server;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class Client {
    private final ObjectOutputStream out;
    private final ObjectInputStream in;
    private final Robot robot;
    
    public Client(String serverMachine,String clientname)
            throws IOException,AWTException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("servermachine",port);
        robot = new Robot();
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        out.writeObject(clientname);
        out.flush();
    }
    public void run() throws ClassNotFoundException{
        try{
            while(true){
                RobotAction action = (RobotAction) in.readObject();
                Object result = action.execute(robot);
                if(result !=null)
                {
                    out.writeObject(result);
                    out.flush();
                    out.reset();
                    
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Connection closed");
            
          }
      }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Client client = new Client(args[0], args[1]);
        client.run();

       }
             
    }
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
> at com.server.Client.main(Client.java:47)`

Comment: You didn't pass any arguments while starting the java application.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Seems the OP passed 1 argument.

Comment: @peter.petrov You are right.

Answer (score 2):

When running your program you need to pass (at least) 2 arguments to it. 
Your problem is that this one `args[1]` doesn't exist and that's because you're passing 1 argument only when running your program. So you're accessing the element `args[1]` but the `args` array contains only 1 element (`args[0]`) and not 2 (`args[0]` and `args[1]`).